# SSIS Error in ODBC connection manager when package is run on other computer than developers

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have created an `SSIS` package which connects to a database through `ODBC`.

The package runs perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2012 and also outside VS2012 on the computer which I developed the program. However, when I run the package on another computer it doesn't run ANYMORE. It ran the day before yesterday without problems on a test-machine. It didn't yesterday and it doesn't today on the same testmachine, while it still runs on the development-pc.

The package uses a connectionstring and therefore I've set the protection-level to "SaveSensitiveDataWithKey". I am running the package in a C# console-app (but have also tried executing the dtsx-file itself outside my Console-app). It works fine on my development PC either way and does not either way on the testmachine.

The error I get is:

```
"Error in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package/Connection manager 'nameOfTheServer' : There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.

Error in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/ODBC Source [72] : The Acquire Connection method call to the connection manager 'nameOfTheServer' failed with error code 0xC0014009."
```

I have googled the error code and the suggestions I've come across all seem to rally around 32vs64 bit issues. I've tried to run it both as 32 and 64 bit but no difference.
My Console-app is built to target x86, so I think that it runs the program (and thereby the package) in 32 bit.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: On the test machine, can you connect to the database using some other tool than SSIS, to make sure theres not a network issue?

Comment: Yes, I can access the database through Excel fx on the test machine.

Comment: Can you verify that Integration services 2012 is installed on the test machine? If you run `dtexec /?` the version number should match on each machine. You can also try running the package with the `/X86` flag.

Comment: Reduce the variables to find the issue: Use DTEXEC.EXE (i.e. in a batch file) to run it on your DEV pc, and make sure it works. Now log in to the test PC as yourself and use the same batch file to run it. Does it work? Also make sure you are not using a DSN (data source name) to access your data as this requires the data source name to be set up on the other PC. What would be most helpful of all is to establish what changed between the days that work and the days that didn't work.

Comment: Integration services 2012 is installed on the test machine. dtexec /? returns different version numbers on dev-machine and test machine, but I can't find a way to update the test machines version. I have just tried to build and run the program on the test machine to see if that makes any difference (copying the project to the test machine and build it in VS2013 after I installed VS2013 yesterday). I still get the same error in the Console and the output in VS2013 ends with (0xc000013a). Though I just reinstalled windows fresh yesterday morning on test machine.